# Strange behavior when adding columns to a table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an interesting issue with a table. I'm using "content editable" to write directly to the table, and have a method to write what the user enters into a hidden field, so that the entered data can be submitted. The users are going to need the ability to add rows and columns.

Everything works pretty good until I add a column and try to write to the hidden input. What is interesting is that if I add a row, the cell that exists from an added column AND an added row, does not fail.

Test it like this:

1. Click the add column button.
2. Try to enter data into one of the new cells.
3. Then add a row by clicking "A" in the first column, it will add a new row directly below the row you clicked in. (helpful to enter data in some cells to keep track of which row is the new row.)
4. Now go to the last column, which is the column that you added and enter data into the new row cell. It will not fail.

I'm pretty baffled by this.

Below is a full HTML file so you can just take it and run it locally.

Thanks!!!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TRADE REPORT DRIVER</title>
<style>
.positionPop
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    height: 250px;
    width: 400px;
}
</style>

<script language='javascript'>

function processNemaForm() {
        var elm = "";
        for(i=0; i < document.nemaForm.length; i++) {
            elm = elm + document.nemaForm.elements[i].name + "=" + document.nemaForm.elements[i].value + "<br>";
            //alert(elm);
        }
        document.write(elm);
    }

    function isNema() {
        if(document.getElementById("nemaBox").checked == true) {
            document.nemaForm.reportCategory.value = "NEMA";
            document.nemaForm.reportCategory.disabled = true;
        } else {
            document.nemaForm.reportCategory.value = "";
            document.nemaForm.reportCategory.disabled = false;
        }
    }

    function openLabelPop(whatId) {
        document.rowLabelPopForm.rowLabelPopPassedLabelId.value = whatId;
        document.getElementById('rowLabelPop').style.display = "";
        document.rowLabelPopForm.rowLabelPopText.value = document.nemaForm[whatId +"value"].value
        document.rowLabelPopForm.rowLabelPopText.focus();
    }

    function saveButton() {
        var passedLabelId = document.rowLabelPopForm.rowLabelPopPassedLabelId.value;
        document.getElementById(passedLabelId).innerHTML = document.rowLabelPopForm.rowLabelPopText.value;
        document.nemaForm[passedLabelId +"value"].value = document.rowLabelPopForm.rowLabelPopText.value;
        document.getElementById('rowLabelPop').style.display = "none";
        document.rowLabelPopForm.rowLabelPopText.value = "";
        document.rowLabelPopForm.rowLabelPopPassedLabelId.value = "";
    }

    function openBodyPop(whatId) {
            document.bodyPopForm.bodyPopPassedLabelId.value = whatId;
            document.getElementById('bodyPop').style.display = "";
            document.bodyPopForm.item.focus();
    }

    function cancelBodyPop() {
            var passedBodyId = document.bodyPopForm.bodyPopPassedLabelId.value;
            document.nemaForm[passedBodyId + "value"].value = "";
            document.bodyPopForm.bodyPopPassedLabelId.value = "";
            document.bodyPopForm.item.value = "";
            document.getElementById('addEmUp').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('bodyPop').style.display = "none";
    }

    function addItems() {
        document.bodyPopForm.item.focus();
        var passedBodyId = document.bodyPopForm.bodyPopPassedLabelId.value;

        var newItem = document.bodyPopForm.item.value;

        var savedItems = document.nemaForm[passedBodyId + "value"].value;
        if(savedItems == "" || savedItems == null) {
            var allItems =  newItem;
        } else {
            var allItems = savedItems + " + " + newItem;
        }

        document.getElementById('addEmUp').innerHTML = allItems;

        document.nemaForm[passedBodyId + "value"].value = allItems;

        document.bodyPopForm.item.value = "";
        document.bodyPopForm.item.focus();
    }

    function writeItemsToForm() {
        var passedBodyId = document.bodyPopForm.bodyPopPassedLabelId.value;

        var savedItems = document.nemaForm[passedBodyId + "value"].value;

        document.getElementById(passedBodyId).innerHTML = savedItems;

        document.getElementById('bodyPop').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('addEmUp').innerHTML = "";
    }

    function addRow(whatRow) {
        var table = document.getElementById('nemaTable');

        var e = table.rows.length-1;
        var rl = table.rows[e].cells.length;
        var insertRow = e;

        for(i=0; i < table.rows.length-1; i++) {
            //get the actual table object row index of the passed row (whatRow) and the insert the row there instead of at whatRow, which is wrong after the first inserted row.

            if(whatRow == document.getElementById("nemaTable").rows[i].id) {

                insertRow = i+1;
            }
        }

        var tr = table.insertRow(insertRow);
        e++;
        var rowId = "nemaRow"+e;
        tr.id = rowId;

        for(var c =0;  c < rl; c++) {
            table.rows[insertRow].insertCell(c);
            cc= c+1;

            if(c==0) {
                table.rows[insertRow].cells[c].innerHTML  = "<td><a onClick=addRow('"+rowId+"')>A-</a><a onClick=openLabelPop('label"+e+"')>P-</a><input type='hidden' name='label"+e+"value'><div id='label"+e+"'></div></td>";
            } else {
                table.rows[insertRow].cells[c].innerHTML  = "<td><div onKeyUp=populateRowHiddenField('row"+e+"add"+c+"','row"+e+"add"+c+"value','nemaForm')><input type='hidden' name='row"+e+"add"+c+"value'><div contentEditable id='row"+e+"add"+c+"'></div></div></td>";
            }
        }
    }

    function addColumn() {
        var table = document.getElementById('nemaTable');
        var cl = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
            var rc = r+1;
            table.rows[r].insertCell(cl);

            if(r==0) {
                table.rows[r].cells[cl].innerHTML = "<td>WEIRD LABEL CELL</td>";
            } else {
                table.rows[r].cells[cl].innerHTML =  "<td><div onKeyUp=populateRowHiddenField('row"+r+"add"+cl+"','row"+r+"add"+cl+"value','nemaForm')<input type='hidden' name='row"+r+"add"+cl+"value'><div contentEditable id='row"+r+"add"+cl+"'></div></div></td>";
            }
        }
    }

    function populateRowHiddenField(rowId,hiddenField,form) {

            document.nemaForm[hiddenField].value = document.getElementById(rowId).innerHTML;
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="column +" onClick="addColumn()" border=0 style='cursor:hand'>

<div id='rowLabelPop' style='display:none' class='positionPop'>
    <form name='rowLabelPopForm'>
        <input type='hidden' name='rowLabelPopPassedLabelId'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Label Name:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='rowLabelPopText'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td coldiv='2'><a onClick='saveButton()' >SAVE</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<div id='bodyPop' style='display:none' class='positionPop'>
    <form name='bodyPopForm'>
    <input type='hidden' name='bodyPopPassedLabelId'>
    <input type='hidden' name='bodyPopItemValues'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='text' name='item'><a onClick='addItems()'>Add</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div id='addEmUp'></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a onClick="writeItemsToForm()">Save</td>
                <td><a onClick="cancelBodyPop()">Cancel</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

<form name="nemaForm">

<p><p>
drop down on row labels for nema reports
<table  id='nemaTable' border='1'>
    <tr id='nemaHeaderRow'>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value="" size='8'>
            <select name=''>
                <option value='Invoice'>I</option>
                <option value='Orders'>O</option>
                <option value='Percentage'>P</option>
                <option value='Subtotal'>S</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value="" size='8'>
            <select name=''>
                <option value='Invoice'>I</option>
                <option value='Orders'>O</option>
                <option value='Percentage'>P</option>
                <option value='Subtotal'>S</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value="" size='8'>
            <select name=''>
                <option value='Invoice'>I</option>
                <option value='Orders'>O</option>
                <option value='Percentage'>P</option>
                <option value='Subtotal'>S</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value="" size='8'>
            <select name=''>
                <option value='Invoice'>I</option>
                <option value='Orders'>O</option>
                <option value='Percentage'>P</option>
                <option value='Subtotal'>S</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value="" size='8'>
            <select name=''>
                <option value='Invoice'>I</option>
                <option value='Orders'>O</option>
                <option value='Percentage'>P</option>
                <option value='Subtotal'>S</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value="" size='8'>
            <select name=''>
                <option value='Invoice'>I</option>
                <option value='Orders'>O</option>
                <option value='Percentage'>P</option>
                <option value='Subtotal'>S</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value="" size='8'>
            <select name=''>
                <option value='Invoice'>I</option>
                <option value='Orders'>O</option>
                <option value='Percentage'>P</option>
                <option value='Subtotal'>S</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value="" size='8'>
            <select name=''>
                <option value='Invoice'>I</option>
                <option value='Orders'>O</option>
                <option value='Percentage'>P</option>
                <option value='Subtotal'>S</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value="" size='8'>
            <select name=''>
                <option value='Invoice'>I</option>
                <option value='Orders'>O</option>
                <option value='Percentage'>P</option>
                <option value='Subtotal'>S</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='nemaRow1'>
        <td><a onClick="addRow('nemaRow1')">A-</a><a onClick="openLabelPop('label1')">P-</a><input type='hidden' name='label1value'><div id='label1'></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row1add1','row1add1value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row1add1value'><div contentEditable id='row1add1'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row1add2','row1add2value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row1add2value'><div contentEditable id='row1add2'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row1add3','row1add3value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row1add3value'><div contentEditable id='row1add3'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row1add4','row1add4value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row1add4value'><div contentEditable id='row1add4'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row1add5','row1add5value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row1add5value'><div contentEditable id='row1add5'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row1add6','row1add6value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row1add6value'><div contentEditable id='row1add6'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row1add7','row1add7value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row1add7value'><div contentEditable id='row1add7'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row1add8','row1add8value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row1add8value'><div contentEditable id='row1add8'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row1add9','row1add9value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row1add9value'><div contentEditable id='row1add9'></div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='nemaRow2'>
        <td><a onClick="addRow('nemaRow2')">A-</a><a onClick="openLabelPop('label2')">P-</a><input type='hidden' name='label2value'><div id='label2'></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row2add1','row2add1value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row2add1value'><div contentEditable id='row2add1'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row2add2','row2add2value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row2add2value'><div contentEditable id='row2add2'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row2add3','row2add3value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row2add3value'><div contentEditable id='row2add3'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row2add4','row2add4value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row2add4value'><div contentEditable id='row2add4'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row2add5','row2add5value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row2add5value'><div contentEditable id='row2add5'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row2add6','row2add6value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row2add6value'><div contentEditable id='row2add6'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row2add7','row2add7value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row2add7value'><div contentEditable id='row2add7'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row2add8','row2add8value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row2add8value'><div contentEditable id='row2add8'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row2add9','row2add9value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row2add9value'><div contentEditable id='row2add9'></div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='nemaRow3'>
        <td><a onClick="addRow('nemaRow3')">A-</a><a onClick="openLabelPop('label3')">P-</a><input type='hidden' name='label3value'><div id='label3'></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row3add1','row3add1value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row3add1value'><div contentEditable id='row3add1'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row3add2','row3add2value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row3add2value'><div contentEditable id='row3add2'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row3add3','row3add3value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row3add3value'><div contentEditable id='row3add3'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row3add4','row3add4value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row3add4value'><div contentEditable id='row3add4'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row3add5','row3add5value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row3add5value'><div contentEditable id='row3add5'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row3add6','row3add6value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row3add6value'><div contentEditable id='row3add6'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row3add7','row3add7value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row3add7value'><div contentEditable id='row3add7'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row3add8','row3add8value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row3add8value'><div contentEditable id='row3add8'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row3add9','row3add9value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row3add9value'><div contentEditable id='row3add9'></div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='nemaRow4'>
        <td><a onClick="addRow('nemaRow4')">A-</a><a onClick="openLabelPop('label4')">P-</a><input type='hidden' name='label4value'><div id='label4'></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row4add1','row4add1value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row4add1value'><div contentEditable id='row4add1'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row4add2','row4add2value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row4add2value'><div contentEditable id='row4add2'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row4add3','row4add3value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row4add3value'><div contentEditable id='row4add3'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row4add4','row4add4value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row4add4value'><div contentEditable id='row4add4'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row4add5','row4add5value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row4add5value'><div contentEditable id='row4add5'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row4add6','row4add6value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row4add6value'><div contentEditable id='row4add6'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row4add7','row4add7value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row4add7value'><div contentEditable id='row4add7'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row4add8','row4add8value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row4add8value'><div contentEditable id='row4add8'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row4add9','row4add9value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row4add9value'><div contentEditable id='row4add9'></div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='nemaRow5'>
        <td><a onClick="addRow('nemaRow5')">A-</a><a onClick="openLabelPop('label5')">P-</a><input type='hidden' name='label5value'><div id='label5'></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row5add1','row5add1value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row5add1value'><div contentEditable id='row5add1'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row5add2','row5add2value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row5add2value'><div contentEditable id='row5add2'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row5add3','row5add3value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row5add3value'><div contentEditable id='row5add3'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row5add4','row5add4value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row5add4value'><div contentEditable id='row5add4'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row5add5','row5add5value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row5add5value'><div contentEditable id='row5add5'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row5add6','row5add6value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row5add6value'><div contentEditable id='row5add6'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row5add7','row5add7value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row5add7value'><div contentEditable id='row5add7'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row5add8','row5add8value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row5add8value'><div contentEditable id='row5add8'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row5add9','row5add9value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row5add9value'><div contentEditable id='row5add9'></div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='nemaRow6'>
        <td><a onClick="addRow('nemaRow6')">A-</a><a onClick="openLabelPop('label6')">P-</a><input type='hidden' name='label6value'><div id='label6'></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row6add1','row6add1value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row6add1value'><div contentEditable id='row6add1'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row6add2','row6add2value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row6add2value'><div contentEditable id='row6add2'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row6add3','row6add3value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row6add3value'><div contentEditable id='row6add3'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row6add4','row6add4value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row6add4value'><div contentEditable id='row6add4'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row6add5','row6add5value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row6add5value'><div contentEditable id='row6add5'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row6add6','row6add6value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row6add6value'><div contentEditable id='row6add6'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row6add7','row6add7value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row6add7value'><div contentEditable id='row6add7'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row6add8','row6add8value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row6add8value'><div contentEditable id='row6add8'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row6add9','row6add9value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row6add9value'><div contentEditable id='row6add9'></div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='nemaRow7'>
        <td><a onClick="addRow('nemaRow7')">A-</a><a onClick="openLabelPop('label7')">P-</a><input type='hidden' name='label7value'><div id='label7'></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row7add1','row7add1value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row7add1value'><div contentEditable id='row7add1'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row7add2','row7add2value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row7add2value'><div contentEditable id='row7add2'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row7add3','row7add3value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row7add3value'><div contentEditable id='row7add3'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row7add4','row7add4value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row7add4value'><div contentEditable id='row7add4'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row7add5','row7add5value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row7add5value'><div contentEditable id='row7add5'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row7add6','row7add6value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row7add6value'><div contentEditable id='row7add6'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row7add7','row7add7value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row7add7value'><div contentEditable id='row7add7'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row7add8','row7add8value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row7add8value'><div contentEditable id='row7add8'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row7add9','row7add9value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row7add9value'><div contentEditable id='row7add9'></div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='nemaRow8'>
        <td><a onClick="addRow('nemaRow8')">A-</a><a onClick="openLabelPop('label8')">P-</a><input type='hidden' name='label8value'><div id='label8'></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row8add1','row8add1value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row8add1value'><div contentEditable id='row8add1'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row8add2','row8add2value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row8add2value'><div contentEditable id='row8add2'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row8add3','row8add3value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row8add3value'><div contentEditable id='row8add3'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row8add4','row8add4value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row8add4value'><div contentEditable id='row8add4'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row8add5','row8add5value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row8add5value'><div contentEditable id='row8add5'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row8add6','row8add6value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row8add6value'><div contentEditable id='row8add6'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row8add7','row8add7value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row8add7value'><div contentEditable id='row8add7'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row8add8','row8add8value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row8add8value'><div contentEditable id='row8add8'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row8add9','row8add9value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row8add9value'><div contentEditable id='row8add9'></div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='nemaRow9'>
        <td><a onClick="addRow('nemaRow9')">A-</a><a onClick="openLabelPop('label9')">P-</a><input type='hidden' name='label9value'><div id='label9'></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row9add1','row9add1value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row9add1value'><div contentEditable id='row9add1'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row9add2','row9add2value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row9add2value'><div contentEditable id='row9add2'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row9add3','row9add3value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row9add3value'><div contentEditable id='row9add3'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row9add4','row9add4value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row9add4value'><div contentEditable id='row9add4'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row9add5','row9add5value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row9add5value'><div contentEditable id='row9add5'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row9add6','row9add6value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row9add6value'><div contentEditable id='row9add6'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row9add7','row9add7value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row9add7value'><div contentEditable id='row9add7'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row9add8','row9add8value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row9add8value'><div contentEditable id='row9add8'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row9add9','row9add9value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row9add9value'><div contentEditable id='row9add9'></div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='nemaRow10'>
        <td><a onClick="addRow('nemaRow10')">A-</a><a onClick="openLabelPop('label10')">P-</a><input type='hidden' name='label10value'><div id='label10'></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row10add1','row10add1value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row10add1value'><div contentEditable id='row10add1'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row10add2','row10add2value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row10add2value'><div contentEditable id='row10add2'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row10add3','row10add3value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row10add3value'><div contentEditable id='row10add3'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row10add4','row10add4value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row10add4value'><div contentEditable id='row10add4'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row10add5','row10add5value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row10add5value'><div contentEditable id='row10add5'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row10add6','row10add6value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row10add6value'><div contentEditable id='row10add6'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row10add7','row10add7value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row10add7value'><div contentEditable id='row10add7'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row10add8','row10add8value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row10add8value'><div contentEditable id='row10add8'></div></div></td>
        <td><div onKeyUp="populateRowHiddenField('row10add9','row10add9value','nemaForm')"><input type='hidden' name='row10add9value'><div contentEditable id='row10add9'></div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>



</form>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: It is good form to create a working example, at a site like [Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/). This will make it less burdensome for someone to help you. Also, please clarify, specifically, what your question is. For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: the question is " What is causing the error?" as far as a working example, I'm not sure how burdensome it is to copy code to a file, save as a .html file and open in a browser, but I went to codepen.io and after dealing with all the errors on their landing page decided against creating an account.